# Zombie-Pigmen Farm in Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am wondering what an efficient zombie-pigmen farm layout/design for Minecraft 1.8 is, and how it would be built?

Comment: If I am not mistaken they spawn just like normal monsters just only in the Nether. So it would be safe to assume similar mob farms would work.

Comment: The only complication from a normal minecraft farm is that they aren't naturally hostile. But I guess water would still work.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBLEbJ9ozRA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a large box as a cage. At one end of the box, in the last row of blocks, make a pit.

```
#                           #
#                           #
#                           #
#                           #
########################### #
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          ###
```

Then, make a one-block slot on the end of the wall just behind the pit, and then make a small section and fill it will snow golems. They will automatically attack pigmen, aggravating them (and since pigmen have bad AI compared to most mobs) the pigmen will run towards the snow golems, and fall into the pit.

```
#                           #####
#                           #   #
#                           #   #
#     Pigmen                 SSS#
########################### #####
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          # #
                          ###
```

You can either make the pit far enough to kill the pigmen and have hoppers pick up the drops, or you can make it one-block before killing them, and make a small window that looks onto their feet so you can hit them to also get the exp.

Comment: if the farm is too large and the snowgolems cant see far enough, you can make another pit and reception area with snowgolems on the other side of the farm. This is also infinitely expandable upwards - simply make new layers with snowgolems on top of the previous layer but make the pit connect to the next level.

Answer (score 1):

Another Snow Golem design would be a 1 block thin strip of land, and snow golems could snipe pigmen off into a pit.

Sn_________________________________Pg

()__________________________________()__()

___________________________________()__()

___________________________________()__()

(sorry the graph is so bad, () = block and _ = nothing.)